# Object files, linkers, archives, etc: where can I find an entry-level explanation for all that?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I consider myself a reasonably experienced programmer; however, I am to this day completely unable to explain what an object file is, or what it contains. I have no idea why GCC needs the `-fPIC` option to create a shared library. I don't know what a linker *really* is, or how it works. I have no idea what `ranlib`, `libtool`, `nm`, etc really do. I know how to disassemble a binary file but I'm not sure how to interpret what I see.

In short, like many programmers my understanding of the compilation process is extremely limited; the documentation that's available seems to me to be geared towards people already in the know, and so are the manpages.

Google wasn't too helpful either, and neither was Wikipedia. Therefore, **is there an entry-level explanation of the concepts underlying the translation of a program text into an executable binary?**

Comment: This is a pretty wide question. For example, you say "I know how to disassemble a binary file but I'm not sure how to interpret what I see." The way to resolve this is for you to learn assembly language, and how the assembly language maps to the bytes stored in the file. That's not quick and easy to explain, yet it is merely a facet required to fully answer this question. So, I think it would be unreasonable for there to exist an entry-level explanation for your entire question. It looks like you might enjoy learning assembly, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want John Levine's book *Linkers and Loaders*, the uncorrected proofs of which can be found for free on [his website](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) (but I'd recommend finding the published book).  Everything in the build chain after code generation is covered clearly and with great examples. I can't recommend it highly enough.

Comment: I agree; I've found his book to be extremely useful in understanding the details of all the steps post-compilation. Writing an ELF (or other object format) parser is on my list of background projects because of reading his book.